# Is there such a thing called "the degree of a group"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Wandering on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics) I read

> "These symmetries determine a group called the dihedral group of degree four, denoted ${\displaystyle \mathrm {D} _{4}}$"

Elsewhere (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/General_linear_group) I saw

> "In mathematics, the general linear group of degree $n$"

The former case I wrote seems to me confusing "the degree" with the notion of order of a group : the cardinality of its underlying set.

The latter case seems named according to the number of linearly independent columns of the invertible matrix on which the general linear group is defined

Therefore I'm asking if I'm mistaken and therefore if it might exists a general notion named "degree of group" or if such words are used in particular cases as I pointed out; Could you answer this dilemma?

Comment: In your first quotation, the degree is **not** the order. Note that, in the notation used in that Wikipedia article, the dihedral group $D_4$ is a group of order $8$. The degree of a **permutation group** is the number of elements in the set it acts on, in this case, the four vertices of the square. I don't know if "degree" means anything in the context of abstract groups.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not any general such definition that these usages are special cases of.  I would even say that these usages are not particularly standard--it is *much* more common to refer to "the $n$th dihedral group" or "the $n$th general linear group" than to refer to them as "degree $n$".   The only reason to ever use the less standard term "degree" is to be able to say things like "the degree of this particular dihedral group", which is not something that comes up much.